# How to get json output in php from url

Tags: php

I see there is some more questions about this, but not useful for me.

Here i have the link and following code i am [Link](http://2strok.com/radio.json)

```
<?php 
$json=file_get_contents("http://2strok.com/radio.json");
$details=json_decode($json);
if($details->Response=='True')
?>

<?php echo $details->name[3];?><br>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: my question is how can i get the result from the json link in the php code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$json=file_get_contents("http://2strok.com/radio.json");
$details=json_decode($json,true);
foreach($details as $output) {
    echo $output['name'].'<br>';
}
```

> **Update - get specific name**

```
$json=file_get_contents("http://2strok.com/radio.json");
$details=json_decode($json,true);
foreach($details as $output) {
    if ($output['name']=='FM 101 / Islamabad'){
        echo 'Specific name found: '.$output['name'];
    }
    // echo $output['name'].'<br>';
}
```

Comment: Thankyou so much ;)

Comment: Do u have also any idee how can i get specific name or url? from the json?

Comment: I am quite new here so i do not know so much about the rules here. do u want me to take it back?

Comment: The last code u update it is not giving me any respons?

Comment: It works, it returns this: Specific name found: FM 101 / Islamabad

Comment: Glad I've helped

Answer (score 1):

After json decode, it returns an array of objects, so try this:

```
$json=file_get_contents("http://2strok.com/radio.json");
$details=json_decode($json);

foreach ($details as $detail){
    echo $detail->name;
    echo "<br>";
} 
?>
```